# Swift 3 game button pressed loop

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have an array of images if I pressed the button the image will randomly appear. and there is an image down also called from the array but it appears randomly just once I opened the game. I want to do a conditions statement for button pressed. like I have 5 conditions once the button clicked: 1- if pressed and the image appeared is not same as the UIIMage view down score will be added 
2- if button did not press for 2 seconds will appear down.
3- if button pressed and it is same as the UIimage so game over.
4- If he calculated 4 images down because he didn't hit the image in 2 seconds he will lose.

```
 var array:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "1.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "2.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "3.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "4.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "5.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "6.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "7.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "8.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "9.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "10.png")!]
```

var random = arc4random_uniform(10)

```
@IBAction func myButtonPressed(button: UIButton) {

    var randomNum: UInt32 = 10
    randomNum = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count))

    myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "bird\(randomNum).png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    // myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "\(randomNum).png"), for: UI)


    self.myImage.animationImages = array

    let buttonWidth = myButton.frame.width
    let buttonHeight = myButton.frame.height

    // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
    let viewWidth = myButton.superview!.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = myButton.superview!.bounds.height

    // Compute width and height of the area to contain the button's center
    let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
    let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight

    // Generate a random x and y offset
    let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
    let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

    // Offset the button's center by the random offsets.
    myButton.center.x = xoffset + buttonWidth / 2
    myButton.center.y = yoffset + buttonHeight / 2

   /* for i in array{

        if myButton != myImage{
            randomNum = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count))

        }

        if else

    } */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like this. As for your first condition, what is your UIImage View Variable. Is it another UIImage View that is being displayed on the storyboard?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var array: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "1.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "2.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "3.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "4.png")!,
                            UIImage(named: "5.png")!]



    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    var pressed: Bool = false;
    var score: Int = 0;


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //2nd Condition: if button did not press for 2 seconds will appear down
        if(pressed == false){
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.doSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func isPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        pressed = true;

        var randomNum: UInt32 = 10
        randomNum = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count));

        myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "\(randomNum).png"), for: .normal)

        // 1st Condition: if pressed and the image appeared is not same as the UIIMage view down score will be added
        if( UIImage(named: "\(randomNum).png") != myButton.currentImage){

            //Add View Down Score
            score += 1;
        }
        // 3rd Condition: if button pressed and it is same as the UIimage so game over
        else{

            // Game Over
        }



    }

    func doSomething() {
        // Not sure what you mean by will appear down
        print("Action")
    }

}
```

I am not quite sure what your 4th condition does. Please clarify

Comment: Hi, yes I have UIImage view which is the image down

Comment: And I have myButton which is the second image will randomly appear when I press it and 4 conditions happened.

Comment: Do you have git, perhaps I could pull off ur repository and try to work off what you currently have

Comment: I tried your correction; the image UIImage down is gone. It should be there and appear randomly each time I open the game 
. so accordingly myButton image has the if conditions.

I meant by the image will go down. he lose so the image in condition if he did not press the button in 2-second duration it will go down and kept their if he collected 4 images down he will lose did you got what I mean it kind complicated together. 

What is the function of the game over?

Comment: Any help for this action?

Comment: Hi, sorry I was working on something. I will try to replicate what you want to do tonight. It would be really great if you put your code on some Source Control though (i.e github) so I can pull off it and work with what you have. Do you have a Github?